Reference request : mean first passage time problem in real-life applications
I am currently looking for references which study the problem of computing the Mean First Passage Time (MFPT) and/or the First Passage Time Density (FPTD) in dimensions $d\ge 2$ from a numerical/application perspective.
To give a bit more context, given a bounded domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^d$, and a stochastic process $(X_t)$ satisfying a Langevin SDE with $X_0\in\Omega$, the First Passage Time (FPT) $\tau$ is defined as the smallest $t\ge0$ such that $X_t\in\partial \Omega$. The problem of computing the FPT comes up often in many fields such as chemistry, neuroscience and even psychology.
It can be shown that the probability density function of $X_t$ is a solution of the Fokker-Planck equation. From there, one can derive PDEs solved by the PDF of $\tau$ and its expectation $\mathbb E[\tau]$, which are the quantities I'm interested in. However, outside of the simplest settings, no closed-form solutions are known and numerical approximations are needed to compute them.
Therefore my question is : could you please provide me with reasonably recent (ideally published after 2015) articles or books where the FPTD and/or MFPT in dimension $\ge2$ are computed using numerical tools ? My goal is to have an understanding of what the state-of-the-art numerical methods for this problem are, and have an eventual benchmark of comparison for a potential alternative method. My literature search has not been very fruitful so far, and I suspect it might be because I do not have the right keywords...
Thank you for your time !

Here are relevant (but not fully satisfying, I'll explain why) references I've found so far :

Efficient numerical approximation of a non-regular Fokker–Planck equation associated with first-passage time distributions by Boehm et al. (2022) : this is unfortunately concerned with one-dimensional domains only
Fast solutions for the first-passage distribution of diffusion models with space-time-dependent drift functions and time-dependent boundaries by Boehm et al. (2021) : again, treats the one-dimensional case only
Mean exit time for diffusion on irregular domains by Simpson et al. (2021) : does not treat the Fokker-Planck equation, but a simple diffusion instead.
Studying First Passage Problems using Neural Networks: A Case Study in the Slit-Well Microfluidic Device by Nagel et al. (2022) : very close to what I'm looking for, but the boundary of the domain is in some parts reflexive instead of absorbing (making it rather a narrow escape problem)
The book Theory and Applications of Stochastic Processes by Zeev Schuss is a very good reference to understand the theory, but no numerics of the FPT problem are discussed there
Lastly, this (unanswered) MSE question is also relevant : What is the probability distribution function of mean hitting-time in a d-dimensional Brownian motion?

